# base-uri function in schematron for validating xml probatron + saxon

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, saxon, xml-validation

We used *probatron* and *saxon* to validate a test xml using a given **sch** file in our java application. Recently, a new rule has been added to the **sch** file such as

```
<let name="foo" value="base-uri()">
```

and some rules use that value, but $foo contains empty string and the rules fail. Where do I have to set this value? I added xml:base tags to the test xml as stated in https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/ but it did not worked. Do I have to set sth in the java side?

Answer (score 0):

We used probatron4j for java based schematron handling:

Java source part:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory t = org.probatron.Utils.getTransformerFactory();
// create xml readers, perfor template processing, apply xslt
// as stated in the probatron4j examples
// ...

t.transform(getCandidateSource(), new StreamResult(baos));
```

our fix includes:

```
Source source = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(..

// or

Source source = new StreamSource(canditateURL.openStream()..

// depending on whether input source is file or url based

// below is the fix, we set path of file or exteral form of the url

source.setSystemId(pathOrUrl);
```

Final result: The value we set as systemid is set into the return value of the `base-uri()` function val in the schema.

---

<sub>This answer was posted ahttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692818/base-uri-function-in-schematron-for-validating-xml-probatron-saxon by the OP [benchpresser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2082488/benchpresser) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>